# How to hide button based user?

Tags: button, odoo-8, openerp-8

I'm developing an OpenERP 8.0 Module and in a certain point of this process a user can take a  workflow of his responsibility. I tried this:

```
_columns = {
        'check' : fields.function(_get_check, type='boolean', obj='stock_picking', method=True),
    }

<button name="force_assign" states="confirmed,waiting,partially_available"  type="workflow" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('check', '=', True), '|']}"/>
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Unknown field check in domain ["|",["check","=",true],"|",["state","not in",["confirmed","waiting","partially_available"]]]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

_columns = {
        'check' : fields.function(_get_check, type='boolean', obj='stock_picking', method=True, **store=True**),
    }

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Add field 'check' to the view with the button:

```
<field name="check" invisible="1"/>
```